# Need a little help with dconf formatting

Tags: 14.04, dconf

Simple question which way is correct or is it even really matter to a program, if I edit Unity Dash Lenses with `dconf` e.g. I want to use only `whatever1.scope` for default `always-search`, by default there's `['whatever1.scope'.'whatever2.scope'.'whatever3.scope'.'whatever4.scope']` so which way should I edit with brackets and quote marks included `['whatever1.scope']` or just quote marks enough `'whatever1.scope'`? The same is for disabled `.scopes` if I only want to disable `'whatever4.scope'` are the quote marks enough or brackets should be included as well?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get** the current settings (list) in a terminal, it is:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Lenses always-search
```

which outputs a list (for example):

```
['applications.scope', 'music.scope', 'videos.scope', 'files.scope']
```

**To set** a (changed) list:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses always-search "['applications.scope']"
```

So change `get` to set, put the list between quote marks, items in the list between (single) quotemarkes.

The format is pretty much (exactly) what you see in dconf editor:

[image]

When you set the list via terminal, just put it between quote marks.