# Is it possible to make Dash open applications scope by default?

Tags: unity-dash

I know that in Ubuntu Unity 7, I can open the applications scope by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on the keyboard, and by right clicking on the Ubuntu logo , selecting Applications.

I was wondering if by pressing just the Super key or clicking the Ubuntu menu, the Applications scope can be called.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Ubuntuser, I would have sworn it worked this morning, but my mind may have played tricks on me, since the applications were the only ones to pop up. That is however different from actually *selecting* the Applications lens. I will look further and remove my answer for now.

Comment: I also just found a dupe! Which has no satisfying answer as well. http://askubuntu.com/questions/479363/how-to-set-application-lens-as-default-in-unity-dash-view-and-search-results