# Explicit pictures show when searching "gedit" in Ubuntu Dash

Tags: unity-dash, search, privacy

Recently at work I searched the Unity Dash for `gedit` and there were explicit pictures in the search result. The picture shows in "Reference" field when I search "gedit" only..

It was very embarrassing to see those files in the list in front of my co-workers.

How can I prevent such incidents from happening again?

**Update**: If I deselect the `Reference` field in Filter results, these explicit pictures go away.

But *why* was I being shown genitals at all? Is there any risk they'll come back?

Comment: Ubuntu Dash, searches local files you have on your pc... Also Online sources but, they - to the best of my knowledge - don't have porn on there sites.

Comment: @ByteCommander it shows in "Reference". I didn't do anything special..

Comment: Cut the guy some slack and act professional , people !

Comment: To understand this: Go to https://www.wikipedia.org/ and type `gedit` into the search field. Within the top results, there are the articles *Genetical modification and mutilation* and *Genital wart*, including an images for both...

Comment: This is a bug - the dash should have a *safe* search of online sources to prevent this

Comment: @Xiaokun I would simply say "do not use unity", as IMO having online search results within a launcher search is inherently prone to such troubles.

Comment: I'm concerned if this is reallly achievable. The only way I see is that sites should have a rating in general. Since Wikipedia has a very open content audience, NSFW content will appear regularly and implementing a software solution to filter the results automatically will require much muscle. NSFW content should be disabled by default and only enabled by a user desiring to do so.

Comment: FWIW, "gedit" or "gedik" is slang for horny or excited in Malay.

Comment: @cheshire Heck, I know it's a comment, but you can't provide "don't use xy" as a solution. I mean 90% of SuperUser questions would be obsolete if we could say "Don't use Windows." ;P

Comment: @OddDev - Yes, true, even though it is probably the best answer to 95% of those questions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<sub>This answer was written *before* you explained that the embarrassing results don't come from a list of recently used local files, but from the <kbd>References</kbd> scope.

It mainly targets at disabling local files/application history, but also **disabling online search results from the Dash**. Once you disabled the online results, you won't get those very ugly result thumbnails from Wikipedia any more.</sub>

---

**I wrote a bug report/feature request about this issue** against the `unity-scope-home` on Launchpad to ask for a child protection filter that either entirely blocks NSFW content from the search results in the Dash, only blocks them if they are no exact matches of the query, or only blocks at least their preview thumbnail to make them less offensive.

If you agree with me that this would be useful and you have a Launchpad account (or don't mind creating one - it's free of course and you only need to enter an email address), **please consider confirming this bug.**

You do this by visiting the link below, logging in to Launchpad, and then clicking on the yellow pencil icon next to the line

> This bug affects N persons. Does this bug affect you?

Select **Yes** and click on <kbd>Change</kbd> and you're done.

**Here is the *[link to the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-scope-home/+bug/1560538)*.**

---

#### Old answer (disabling local file/application history and online search results):

To disable recording of your file and application usage that, open the System Settings and go to the **Security & Privacy** options.

[image: System Settings]

Switch to the **Files & Applications** tab:

[image: System Settings > Security & Privacy > Files & Applications]

Here you should turn **Record file and application usage** <kbd>OFF</kbd>. Additionally you can/should also use the <kbd>Clear Usage Data...</kbd> button to get rid of old recordings.

Then you can also disable online search results (***This is where the explicit images in your case were coming from!***). To do that, switch to the **Search** tab.

[image: System Settings > Security & Privacy > Search]

Here you can simply turn **Include online search results** <kbd>OFF</kbd>.

Comment: If this post answers your question and helped you to solve the described problem, please accept it by clicking the round grey tick symbol on the left of it. Thank you.

Comment: I am not kidding. I didn't watch anything special. The picture shows in "Reference" field when I search "gedit"  only..

Comment: @Xiaokun Okay, this is strange. It looks like the "Reference" thing is made for interaction with Zotero (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Zotero), but that should be a tool to collect citations and references for research purposes. Maybe it would still help to disable at least the online search results as described in my answer. Could you please check if the explicit results still appear after that?

Comment: In my ubuntu15, there is no such Security & Privacy. I have found out that the pic is from wikipedia. And long time age, I did search such item...

Comment: I just enabled online search results and saw exactly the same you saw! YUCK! (if it would be at least p0rn - but it's just ugly!)Please do yourself a favour and **disable online search results** as described in my answer! This is horrible and I'll complain about this somewhere for you!

Comment: @Xiaokun Maybe the "Security & Privacy" settings are labeled differently in your language. I added a screenshot so that you can identify it by its icon. You can open the System Settings window e.g. by clicking the gear symbol in your panel in the top right corner of the screen (where also the option to shut down is) and selecting "System Settings...".

Comment: Also please see the latest edit of my answer. I wrote a bug report about this on Launchpad to request a child protection filter in the scope that blocks such NSFW content.

Comment: Mind that possibly (likely) disabling online search on 14.04 (probably another bug) will not survive a restart: see http://askubuntu.com/a/645897/72216

Comment: As of now, those images don't seem to be appearing anymore. Something was probably done server side as I haven't updated anything since the last time I tried. I even tried to enter explicitly porn-prone words, filtering seems to more child-friendly. It still needs to be tweaked a little more, but it's a lot better than before.

Comment: @Dan The results for "gedit" seem to be removed now, but It still isn't child-safe for other search queries...

Comment: I only just created a LP logon recently for something else and would have been happy to report it, but just went to my ubuntu box, and gladly, the search result was clean. I also did some searches that pulled up wiki pages that do have ugly pics, and they weren't present.