# Package responsible for Unity Dash search results (home lens, category "References")

Tags: unity, package-management, unity-dash, lenses, scopes

I want to file a bug against a Unity Dash scope, but I don't know exactly which one it is and which package it belongs to.

The results I want to complain about appear in the home lens, in the **References** category, from the **Wikipedia** source. I did not add or remove anything related to unity scopes and lenses, there are only the default packages for Ubuntu 15.10.

Which package is responsible for displaying the results of this category?

PS: Cause of this question are very inappropriate search results when you look for "gedit" with online search results enabled, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/748917/367990).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just filed my bug report against `unity-scope-home` for now.
If any other package would be more suitable, please still tell me and I'll move the report.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-scope-home/+bug/1560538